# How to show Metamask error in the web browser

Tags: reactjs, metamask, ethers.js

I would like to know how you can get the Metamask error from the browser to show it to your own React web application as example below. I am currently using ethers.js to interact with my contracts.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just made a function error on my new Contract instance. .wait() doesn't exists. Using try and catch block works now like a charm.

```
 try {
    setRareMintLoading(true);
    const result = await client.add(JSON.stringify(randomResult));
    const uri = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${result.path}`;

    await nft.rareMint(account, uri, { value: "30000000000000000" });

    setRareMintLoading(false);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) {
      setRareMintLoading(false);
      alertMessage("Error!", err.message, "warning");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but as for showing the tx error, how about using `try` and `catch`?
like

```js
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

const doSomeTransaction = async () => {
   try {
      await yourContract.someFunction();
   } catch(e) {
     setError(e.message);
     openErrorModal(); // you need to declare this function somewhere to show the error
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this out but it seems it cannot catch the Metamask's error.

Comment: Oh really?
It works fine on my code though...
I can show the alert modal when the transaction failed.
modal:
https://gyazo.com/306d41f8465c2953055959de64182ddc
console error:
https://gyazo.com/835618a68fb2c28ce53df311e4851a0d